# DNN and Paypal sandbox - Incorrect expiry date

Tags: paypal, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I am testing paid memberships for my DNN website with the Paypal sandbox. The subscription goes through smoothly, and the role is correctly added to the user. However, the expiry date of the role is set to 2 yrs from the current date, although the payment was for 1 year only. This is quite surprising for me and I don't know how to find the cause. Any input appreciated.
[image: Screenshot of problem]

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use this component to manage [portal subscriptions](http://www.ventrian.com/Products/Modules/SubscriptionTools.aspx)

The core DNN one always seemed half baked so I adopted the linked component many years ago and tend to still use it for simple PayPal subscription stuff.